# Passing cookies when using wp_remote_get

Tags: cookies, wp-remote-get

I'm working on a plugin that fetches remote RSS feeds using `wp_remote_get`. The problem is that Tumblr requires a cookie for GDPR compliance. This includes RSS feeds. Which means all Tumblr feeds are currently broken.

I found [an example of using CURL to acquire the cookies](https://github.com/Arvedui/tt-rss-tumblr-gdpr) so the feed will load. However, I have little more than a passing acquaintance with `wp_remote_get` and related functions.

How do I implement the cookie getting hack from the example via WordPress' remote get methodology?

**Edit**: To clarify, I need to *get* and then use a cookie. That's two requests; one for the cookie and a second using the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments array for `wp_remote_get` accepts a `cookies` parameter:

```php
$cookies = [];
$cookie = new WP_Http_Cookie( 'cookie_name' );
$cookie->name = 'cookie_name';
$cookie->value = 'your cookie value';
$cookie->expires = 7 * DAY_IN_SECONDS; // expires in 7 days
$cookie->path = '/';
$cookie->domain = '.reddit.com';
$cookies[] = $cookie;

$url = 'https://tumblr.com/some/url/';

$args = [
    'cookies' => $cookies,
];

$response = wp_remote_get( $url, $args );
```

Comment: Does that work for getting the cookie first? If so, how do I nab that?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your request a little. To get the cookies from a `wp_remote_request` method such as `wp_remote_get` or `wp_remote_post`, you can access the `cookies` key of the returned array. e.g. `$r = wp_remote_get( <url> ); print_r( $r['cookies'] );`

Answer (score 1):

Going off of @phatskat answer, you can also pass the values in the constructor as well, and example from WooCommerce is as follows:

```
$cookies = [];
$cookies[] = new WP_Http_Cookie( array(
    'name'  => $name,
    'value' => $value,
));


$args = [
    'cookies' => $cookies,
];

$response = wp_remote_get( $url, $args );
```

Looking at core code though, there is a method to build the cookies when a request is made (@since 2.8.0):
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f547eb617441853b6e316c6f127a2182c12925e3/wp-includes/class-http.php#L775-L797

When CURL or STREAM request is made:
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/57a3f803ae67814b2639ab8816d59c5fa5add441/wp-includes/class-wp-http-curl.php#L93